# Should I use weak event listeners while listening to DependencyProperty changes?

Tags: .net, wpf, events, weak-references, weakeventmanager

I was looking in the framework for an implementation of [WeakEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager.aspx) that listens for changes to DependencyProperties.  I'm a bit confused by the fact that the only weak property change event listener I find, the [PropertyChangedEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager.aspx), is designed to be used on types that implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Does this mean that if you listen to a DependencyProperty for changes

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor
    .FromProperty(target, target.OwnerType)
    .AddValueChanged(component, handler)
```

that I don't have to worry about leaking instances who are kept alive by event registration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DependencyPropertyDescriptor` leaks big time, I had lot of issues because of it. Unless you explicitly call `RemoveValueChanged` all your components will be rooted. Internally it maintains a `HashTable` of `EventHandler`. Here is what it does:

```
if (this.valueChangedHandlers == null)
  this.valueChangedHandlers = new Hashtable();
EventHandler eventHandler = (EventHandler) this.valueChangedHandlers[component];
this.valueChangedHandlers[component] = (object) Delegate.Combine((Delegate) eventHandler, (Delegate) handler);
```

Since property descriptors are cached, all your components will be rooted.

Comment: Bugger all.  Got a better solution?

Comment: A siemple and manual solution is to explicitly call `RemoveValueChanged` when stop listening changes.